# No Storyboard Member within my ViewController when calling another view controller

Tags: swift, storyboard, member

When I run my code below within my view controller

```
import UIKit
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let fifthVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "fifthVC") as? FifthViewController

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func twentyLife() {
        fifthVC.lifePointsInt = 20

    }

    @IBAction func thirtyLife() {
        fifthVC.lifePointsInt = 30

    }

    @IBAction func fortyLife() {
        fifthVC.lifePointsInt = 50
    }
}
```

I am getting error

> Value of type '(SecondViewController) -> () -> SecondViewController'
> has no member 'storyboard'

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to do here but to remove that error , you should call the following line inside some function

```
let fifthVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "fifthVC") as? FifthViewController
```

You can either call it in `viewDidLoad` or you can make a separate function and call it. But first you need to define `fifthVC` variable in view controller.

```
var fifthVC:UIViewController?
```

Then inside `viewDidLoad`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  fifthVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "fifthVC") as? FifthViewController
 }
```